# Как сделать ImageButton круглой формы?

Tags: android

Как сделать `ImageButton` круглой формы ?

Answer (score 1):

Для создания кастомных обрамлений вьюх используйте [Shape](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape). Создайте xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

Пример использования в макете:

```
<ImageButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/imageButton"
       ...
       android:background="@drawable/circle_button"/>
```